# Where in the table is it stored that /drupal/foo is actually /node/47 in order to mass query to remove /drupal and just leave the /foo part?

Tags: database

/drupal is broken on all the websites, but I want to go into the database and mass query to remove the /drupal and just leave the /foo part.

Answer (score 3):

The table you want is `{url_alias}`.  The `{url_alias.source}`column is the internal path (eg node/123), the `{url_alias.alias}` is the alias itself.

Mucking with the database directly isn't recommended, though.  Your best bet is to use [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Globalredirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect).  The first will allow you to set up patterns, the second will redirect nodes to the alias.

You then use the Delete Aliases (admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk) link and then Bulk Update (admin/config/search/path/update_bulk) to make the new ones.

If you must do this manually, I suggest looking into the what the [Path include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/7) provides as an API, and using that.

Also be sure that you don't actually have a problem with a `$base_url` being set incorrectly in your settings.php